# How is the value of relocation register or base register set initially ? who decides the value at relocation register and how does it change?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I understand that the physical address is calculated by adding the logical address to the value in relocation register. But in order to get the correct physical address of the process, we need to know the correct value of the relocation register.

Who decides the value at relocation register, how is it generated for the first time a process is created and how does it change ?

Comment: What architecture are you talking about?  Most don't have a "limit register", and I don't know any that work in a way that matches what you're describing.  (e.g. x86 segment limits don't *add* to x86 logical addresses.)

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry about that , i mistyped limit register for "relocation register"

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know what architecture you're talking about.  It still doesn't match x86 segmentation, since in x86 a logical address is `segment:offset`, including the two components that combine to make a linear address.  But DOS `.com` and `.exe` use the segment base to relocate programs.

Comment: OSes have to allocate physical memory for processes, so the OS would choose where in physical space it wants the process to go, and relocate the code to that base address (e.g. by putting that value in a register on some architectures, if we're talking about a simplistic scheme without virtual memory to let the OS allocate on a page-by-page basis.)

Comment: that makes sense , yes i was indeed referring to a general scheme irrespective of the arch.  thank you @PeterCordes for your assistance and time